# Div tag target attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to add a target attribute to a div tag (see code below) so that the page "index.html" opens in the same page i.e target_self

```
  <div id="home" style="cursor:pointer;
                 "href="javascript:void(0)" 
                 onclick="window.open('index.html')"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change from `window.open` to `window.location.href =`

Comment: Thanks… If I want to link to index should the code be window.location.href="index.html", or do I need to add the " before index.